# trying to setup wireless

Tags: wireless, dell-vostro

I'm trying to set up wireless on vostro 1520 dell laptop, with latest Ubuntu install. Here's the output of some of the commands that I was told to run:

lshw -C network

```
viggy@ubuntu:~$ lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: 00:24:e8:da:84:25
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168d-1.fw ip=192.168.2.6 latency=0 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:47 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f6004000-f6004fff memory:f6000000-f6003fff memory:f6020000-f603ffff
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0e:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:18 memory:fa000000-fa003fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 0c:60:76:05:ee:74
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=b43 driverversion=3.2.0-29-generic firmware=N/A multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
```

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 03)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 6 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)
0e:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
1a:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): O2 Micro, Inc. Device 10f7 (rev 01)
1a:00.1 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Device 8120 (rev 01)
1a:00.2 Mass storage controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Device 8130 (rev 01)
```

iwconfig

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

** UPDATE **

Here's the output of running sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer :

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done 
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required: 
  dkms 
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them. 
The following packages will be REMOVED: 
  firmware-b43-installer 
The following NEW packages will be installed: 
  firmware-b43-lpphy-installer 
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 79 not upgraded. 
Need to get 3,390 B of archives. 
After this operation, 1,024 B disk space will be freed. 
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y 
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/multiverse firmware-b43-lpphy-installer all 1:015-9 [3,390 B] 
Fetched 3,390 B in 0s (27.3 kB/s)                         
(Reading database ... 187405 files and directories currently installed.) 
Removing firmware-b43-installer ... 
Selecting previously unselected package firmware-b43-lpphy-installer. 
(Reading database ... 187402 files and directories currently installed.) 
Unpacking firmware-b43-lpphy-installer (from .../firmware-b43-lpphy-installer_1%3a015-9_all.deb) ... 
Setting up firmware-b43-lpphy-installer (1:015-9) ... 
No chroot environment found. Starting normal installation 
--2012-11-06 00:50:49--  http://downloads.openwrt.org/sources/broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4.tar.bz2 
Resolving downloads.openwrt.org (downloads.openwrt.org)... 78.24.191.177 
Connecting to downloads.openwrt.org (downloads.openwrt.org)|78.24.191.177|:80... connected. 
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK 
Length: 5986780 (5.7M) [application/octet-stream] 
Saving to: `broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4.tar.bz2' 

100%[================================>] 5,986,780   1.59M/s   in 5.3s    

2012-11-06 00:50:55 (1.07 MB/s) - `broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4.tar.bz2' saved [5986780/5986780] 

broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4/ 
broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4/config/ 
broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4/config/wlconfig_nomimo 
broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4/config/wlconfig_lx_router_apsta_1chipG 
broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4/config/wlconfig_lx_wl_sdstd 
broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4/config/wlconfig_lx_shared 
broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4/config/diffupdate.sh 
broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4/config/wlconfig_lx_router_ap_1chipG 
broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4/config/wlconfig_lx_router_ap 
broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4/config/wlconfig_lx_router_ap_sdstd 
broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4/config/wl.mk 
broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4/config/wltunable_lx_router.h 
broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4/config/wlconfig_lx_router_sta 
broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4/config/wl_default 
broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4/config/wltunable_lx_router_1chipG.h 
broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4/config/wl_hnd 
broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4/config/wlconfig_lx_router_sta_1chipG 
broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4/config/wlconfig_lx_router_apsta 
broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4/config/wlconfig_apdef 
broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4/README 
broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4/linux/ 
broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4/linux/wl_sta.o 
broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4/linux/wl.o 
broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4/linux/wl_ap.o 
broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4/linux/wl_apsta.o 
This file is recognised as: 
  filename   :  wl_apsta.o 
  version    :  478.104 
  MD5        :  bb8537e3204a1ea5903fe3e66b5e2763 
Extracting b43/ucode5.fw 
Extracting b43/pcm5.fw 
Extracting b43/b0g0bsinitvals5.fw 
Extracting b43/a0g0bsinitvals5.fw 
Extracting b43/b0g0initvals5.fw 
Extracting b43/a0g1initvals5.fw 
Extracting b43/a0g0initvals5.fw 
Extracting b43/a0g1bsinitvals5.fw 
Extracting b43/ucode9.fw 
Extracting b43/a0g1initvals9.fw 
Extracting b43/a0g0bsinitvals9.fw 
Extracting b43/b0g0bsinitvals9.fw 
Extracting b43/b0g0initvals9.fw 
Extracting b43/a0g1bsinitvals9.fw 
Extracting b43/a0g0initvals9.fw 
Extracting b43/ucode11.fw 
Extracting b43/n0bsinitvals11.fw 
Extracting b43/n0absinitvals11.fw 
Extracting b43/n0initvals11.fw 
Extracting b43/ucode13.fw 
Extracting b43/b0g0initvals13.fw 
Extracting b43/a0g1bsinitvals13.fw 
Extracting b43/a0g1initvals13.fw 
Extracting b43/lp0bsinitvals13.fw 
Extracting b43/b0g0bsinitvals13.fw 
Extracting b43/lp0initvals13.fw 
Extracting b43/ucode14.fw 
Extracting b43/lp0initvals14.fw 
Extracting b43/lp0bsinitvals14.fw 
Extracting b43/ucode15.fw 
Extracting b43/lp0bsinitvals15.fw 
Extracting b43/lp0initvals15.fw 
Extracting b43/ucode16.fw 
Extracting b43/n0bsinitvals16.fw 
Extracting b43/sslpn0initvals16.fw 
Extracting b43/n0initvals16.fw 
Extracting b43/lp0initvals16.fw 
Extracting b43/sslpn0bsinitvals16.fw 
Extracting b43/lp0bsinitvals16.fw
```

Comment: what is your *question*?

Comment: @EliranMalka how do I get wireless working. For example, the above output says "no wireless extensions" and "wireless disabled". Im trying to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

With the Ubuntu 11.x releases, the proprietary Broadcom drivers stopped
working with the 4311 Broadcom chips (see bug 732677), and perhaps this
bug also affects the 4312 chip. However your chip works fine with the open
b43 driver, but you first need to install its firmware -- easily done with
a package install. If installed, remove the proprietary STA driver (and
its configuration files which  suppress the working b43 driver) by
reversing whatever you did to install them:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and/or run **additional-drivers** and unselect the **Broadcom STA driver**

Check that your removal/deactivation above is complete:
all the lines with  "blacklist b43" should have been removed from all
files in `/etc/modprobe.d`. These blacklist lines suppress  the b43 driver,
so they must be removed -- just the exact "b43" and b43legacy ones, leave
the bcm43xx alone.  Deal with any leftovers:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf  
gksudo gedit any-file-found-with-b43
```

and delete or put a `#` at the beginning.

The proprietary firmware cannot be distributed with the release,so you
have to manually add it. Use a wired connection, and in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
```

and accept the offer to download the Broadcom files, which
will put the Broadcom firmware into /lib/firmware/b43.
If you don't get the offer to download, then purge the package
and try again:

```
sudo apt-get purge b43-fwcutter

sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
```

You can even use the open source firmware (which is what I use):

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

but only one set of firmware is needed (and non-4311 users should
check for needing other versions of the firmware (like
firmware-b43-lpphy-installer).  If both sets of firmware are 
present, the proprietary set in `/lib/firmware/b43` will be used.

With the firmware in place, NetworkManager may start scanning,
if not, manually load the b43 driver module, or just reboot.

```
sudo modprobe b43
```

**NetworkManager** should start scanning and offer a list of possible
connection points within a few seconds.

Select your access point, select the correct encryption method, and enter
your key. If you are not broadcasting your ssid and it does not show up  in
the list of access points, you might have to left click NetworkManager and
select the menu item "connect to hidden network", and enter your ssid. Next
boot, the connection should be automatic.

Comment: I purge and run this install a couple times: sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter. And I dont get any offer to download the Broadcom files. 
I also tried to go to that directory: viggy@ubuntu:/$ cd /lib/firmware/b43
-bash: cd: /lib/firmware/b43: No such file or directory

Comment: I tried running sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer  instead, and by switching to root user, that /lib/firmware/b43 directory exists. And it contains a number of .fw files. But still no wireless.

Comment: I updated my question with the output of running sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer.

Comment: Looks like you got the right "lpphy" set of firmware, do you see any networks listed under the network-manager icon?  Reboot and check for networks?  Noticed the non-lpphy set of firmware was removed, so looks like you tried that first, maybe a purge was needed to get all the wrong fw files, so if things still fail. purge both and then install firmware-b43-lpphy-install again.

Comment: Still "Wireless Networks" and "Enable Wireless" remains grayed out.

Comment: In a terminal run: rfkill list     and ensure no hard blocks or soft blocks are on.  if they are, run rfkill unblock all

Comment: After running, rfkill unblock all, it still shows this: 1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: yes

Comment: hard blocked  implies a switch has turned off the wireless (actual switch or function key) or the module did not load.  Did the module load?  lsmod | grep b43

Comment: hard blocked  implies a switch has turned off the wireless (actual switch or function key) or the module did not load.  Did the b43 module load?  lsmod | grep b43  
If not, recheck that b43 is not blacklisted in any file in /etc/modules.d
Is the wl driver still around -- lsmod | grep wl
It should not be present.
Did the firmware load?  dmesg | grep firm  
and no messages about missing files /lib/firmware/b43/ucode5.fw